# How many ways we can say "I didn't spot your ping"?

Tags: word-choice, gerund-vs-infinitive

One of my colleagues pinged me in chat, but I didn't notice because since I was on a call. Now I want to ping him back that I missed to see his ping and to apologize.

I am not sure *I missed to see* is the correct sentence.

Comment: Just say, "I'm sorry I missed your ping." or "I didn't see your ping. I'm sorry about that." You're right; it isn't correct to say "I missed to see..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -ing here, "I missed *seeing* your ping..."

Here is a list of more verbs where it is often appropriate to use -ing following the verb.

http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-ing-clauses

I notice that in some of these examples, using "X-ing" (gerund) or "to X" (infinitive) would be equally acceptable. For instance:

- I hate eating fried foods before bedtime.
- I hate to eat fried foods before bedtime.

But in other cases, as in your original example, the infinitive sounds wrong.

- I remember walking through the streets of Paris.
- ***** I remember to walk through the streets of Paris.